# Convergence of a sequence $\left\{ f (k) \right\}$ of functions in $C[0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Please help me to understand the basic concepts of the following sequence (apologies in advance for asking simple things probably, but it is heavy for me yet. With your blessings, I can learn more and understand things.):

The sequence $\left\{ f (k) \right\}$ of functions in $C[0,1]$, i.e, the vector space of all complex-valued or real-valued continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ is given by

\begin{align*}
& f_k(x) = 0, & \ 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{k} \\
& f_k(x) = 2\left(k^{\frac{3}{2}}x - k^{\frac{1}{2}} \right), & \ \frac{1}{k} \leq x \leq \frac{3}{2k} \\
& f_k(x) = 2\left(-k^{\frac{3}{2}}x + 2k^{\frac{1}{2}} \right), & \ \frac{3}{2k} \leq x \leq \frac{2}{k} \\
& f_k(x) = 0, & \ \frac{2}{k} \leq x \leq 1 .\\
\end{align*}

Now, please help me to understand how and why the following two are true, namely

(i) $\lVert f_k(x) - f_j(x)\rVert_1 \rightarrow 0$ as $k, \ j  \rightarrow \infty$. Why and how?

(ii) for each $k \geq 2$, there is some $J > k$ for which $\lVert f_k(x) - f_j(x)\rVert_{\infty} > k^{\frac{1}{2}}$ for all $j > J$. Hmm, why and how?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Surely (i) is clear? Fix any x,  and calculate $\lim_{n \to\infty} f_n(x)$

Comment: With respect to (i), I thought that it should be straightforward, but I keep getting infinity. May be I am making some stupid mistakes. Since $f_k(x)$ is non-zero for the two intervals of $x$. If I pick the second interval from the top, and say $x = \frac{3}{2k}$, and obtain the limits, i.e., $\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty } \ 2\left(k^{\frac{3}{2}}\:\left(\frac{3}{2k}\right)\:-\:k^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) = k^{1/2}$, then I get $\infty$!?

Comment: Looks like you are right. That limit is infinity, and hence the question is flawed.

Comment: yeah I think so as well. Probably (ii) and (iii) should be correct, but not sure :(. I will remove (i) just to avoid any misunderstandings further.

Comment: In i), as k tends to infinity, $\dfrac{2}{k} $ tends to 0, so $x \in [\dfrac{2}{k},1]$ as k tends to infinity